# Why is my href link to Facebook profile not working?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've made a portfolio site and the href link to Facebook is the only social media link that won't work. Upon copy and pasting my profile link as I did the other social media links, it seems to not work. I've got this problem on another website I am designing too. Any clues why? Ps I've tried taking out the 's' from https but that still hasn't worked.

```
div class="social-sidebar-buttons"   

     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/chloe.hammond.7"><img src="icons/facebooknudepink.png" target="_blank" alt="Connect with Chloe on Facebook"/></a>                                              
  <a href="https://twitter.com/ChloeHammondx" title="twitter"><img src="icons/twitternudepink.png"  target="_blank" alt="Connect with Chloe on Twitter" /></a>

<a href="https://instagram.com/chloelouisehammond/" title="Instagram"><img src="icons/instagramnude.png" target="_blank" alt="View Chloe's Instagram feed" /></a>

<a href="mailto:chloehammond@live.co.uk" title="email"><img src="icons/mailtonudepink.png" target="_blank" alt="Email Chloe" /></a> 
    </div>
```

And this is the link to the page:
http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/index2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try closing the div by changing:

```
div class="social-sidebar-buttons"
```

to

```
<div class="social-sidebar-buttons">
```

Comment: upvoted this one, because it was the first answer and it is the most complete one. you should mark it as correct answer @ChloeHammond

Answer (score 4):

You need to close the div tag:

```
<div class="social-sidebar-buttons"
```

Answer (score 0):

because your link is wrong ? 

Because dots in "chloe.hammond.7" no ?

Comment: Her chosen username _does_ contain the dots. Anyway, the dots don’t matter – same as with f.e. Gmail usernames, you can type in Facebook usernames without any dots, insert random dots or even mess around with upper- and lowercase – Facebook will redirect all versions to the actual username. `/c.h.l.o.e.h.a.m.m.o.n.d.7` or `/chLOEhamMONd7` for example will just redirect back to `/chloe.hammond.7`